# SharePoint 2010 Search - The search request was unable to connect to the Search Service

Tags: search, sharepoint-foundation

I am using SharePoint 2010 Foundation and I have a problem with the search on there.  Every time I search for something I get the response of **The search request was unable to connect to the Search Service.**

I have spent a lot of time looking at this and I cannot seem to see what is causing the issue.  The SharePoint Foundation Search service is started but there are no services listed on the server for search other than the 'Help Search'.

Also, if I look into my content databases under the 'Manage Database Upgrade Status' it told me that the database is too old...

Could anyone point me in the right direction as to how to resolve these issues as it is sending me mad!!

Comment: Is this a recently upgraded farm?

Comment: @DaveWise - yes, it was recently upgraded. It is a single server farm and was upgraded from WSS3.0 to SP2010 with SP1. Cheers, Luke